# Get absolute path with boost::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, boost, path, filesystems

My current working directory is located at `/home/myuser/program`, I created a `boost::filesystem::path` object pointing to it. I appended `/../somedir` so it becomes `/home/myuser/program/../somedir`. But I need to get its resolved absolute path, which would be `/home/myuser/somedir`.

I have been trying for long time and I do not find any method in [their reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) to do this. There is a method called `make_absolute`, which seems to be supposed to do what I expect, but I have to give it a “root” path argument. Which should it be? do I really need to do this to get the real absolute path? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You say you want an absolute path, but your example shows that you already have an absolute path. The process of removing the `..` components of a path is known as *canonicalization*. For that, you should call [`canonical`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical). It happens to also perform the task of `absolute`, so you don't need to call `absolute` or `make_absolute` first. The `make_absolute` function requires a base path; you can pass it `current_path()` if you don't have anything better.

Comment: Exatcly. I did not want to use the word “canonical” since I was not sure if it also meant resolved symlinks and such, for example. I tried your suggestion and it worked immediately. Thanks.

Comment: Note that canonical throws exception if file do not exists. So you could construct only existing path.

Answer (score 14):

Update, since this still appears to be Google's top hit concerning absolute paths:

**As of Boost 1.57, some of the previously suggested functions have since been removed.**

The solution that worked for me was

```
boost::filesystem::path canonicalPath = boost::filesystem::canonical(previousPath, relativeTo);
```

(using the free-standing method [canonical()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical), defined in boost/filesystem/operations.hpp, which is automatically included via boost/filesystem.hpp)

Important: calling canonical on a path that does not exist (e.g., you want to create a file) will throw an exception. In that case, your next best bet is probably boost::filesystem::absolute(). It will also work for non-existing
paths, but won't get rid of dots in the middle of the path (as in a/b/c/../../d.txt).
Note: Make sure relativeTo refers to a directory, calling parent_path() on paths referring to files (e.g. the opened file that contained a directory or file path relative to itself).

Comment: What is an example path string of "previousPath" and "relativeTo"? I can't quite figure out what the input needs to look like in terms of path style.

Comment: Previous path could something like path("../../readme.txt"), with relativeTo = path("c:/example/test/blah") this should then resolve to "c:/example/readme.txt". Not sure what the relativeTo does (or if a sensible input is even required), if previous path is already absolute.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation shows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute) that the `make_absolute` has an *optional* second parameter that defaults to your current path:

`path absolute(const path& p, const path& base=current_path());`

Try it without the second parameter and see if it returns the results you're looking for.

Comment: That is one of the inconsistencies that annoyed me a little, in the docs. There is a `make_absolute` method that has one parameter, when I follow the link, it directs me to the documentation of an `absolute()` function which accepts two parameters. Still, doing it like `absolute(pathObject).string()` will return the same unresolved path. This is what you suggested, right?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to give it a “root” path argument.

[Check the docs:](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute) you don't *have* to give it anything; it has a default second parameter. Namely, the current directory.

Relative paths are relative to some directory. Thus, when making a path absolute, you need to know what it should be absolute *relative to*. That's the "root path": the directory it is relative to.

Answer (score 0):

```
// input: d:\\tmp\\\\a/../VsDebugConsole.png
// output: d:\\tmp\\VsDebugConsole.png
static std::wstring fix_path(std::wstring path)
{
    //boost::replace_all(path, L"\\\\", L"\\");
    //boost::replace_all(path, L"//", L"/");
    boost::filesystem::path bpath(path);
    bpath = boost::filesystem::system_complete(bpath);

    return bpath.wstring();
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation?